# 0 randomly becomes 55?

Tags: objective-c, swift, integer, nsdictionary

I have an app in which I pass an dictionary of type [string:[int]] from a swift file to an objective c file, then as NSDictionary. Through that process, the data formats get all screwed up, but in the end I am able to access each array of ints from a string, as would be expected from an NSDictionary. Unfortunately, somewhere along the line the integers get converted to type 'id', and to change that back to int, I did this:

`NSLog(@"%d",(int)theThreeNotes[@"0"][0])`

theThreeNotes[@"0"][0] should be 0, but it is logged as 55. How do you fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dictionary is passed to Objective-C, all the integers will become `NSNumber` instances. `NSDictionary`/`NSArray` cannot hold primitive values. That means you will have to call `integerValue` on the number, not cast it blindly to `int`.

Or just print it using:

```
NSLog(@"%@", theThreeNotes[@"0"][0])
```

Comment: Or `NSLog(@"%d",[theThreeNotes[@"0"][0] intValue])`.

Comment: @rmaddy ```integerValue```

Comment: @Dan No, `intValue` since the format specifier is `%d`.